# Bootstrap MVC4 scaffolding for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC4 application in Visual Studio 2012. I am also using twitter bootstrap.

Whenever I generate a new Controller, VS2012 will automatically generate default CRUD pages for me, which is nice.

However I am getting tired modifying the pages so that the DIVs are laid out the way bootstrap needs it.

Is there a VS2012 plugin that help generate these views the way bootstrap expects it to be?

Here is a sample div generated by VS2012.

```html
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

.. and I will manually change it to be...

```html
<div class="editor-label control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="editor-field controls">
        @Html.EditorFor( model => model.Name, "CustomTemplate", 
                                     new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I came here to ask this exact question ;)

Comment: I came here to ask this exact question, too

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC uses [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) to scaffold Views (and also Controllers) through the Add View and Add Controller dialogs.

You can easilly customize these templates with your custom Bootsrtap markup.

You just need to copy the `CodeTemplates` directory from (the path can be different on your machine depending on the installed OS, VS, and ASP.NET MVC version)

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\
    Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4
```

Inside your MVC project under a `CodeTemplates` directory and they are ready for customization.

Here is good step by step guide on the process: [Modifying the default code generation/scaffolding templates in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

If you want to take the scaffolding one step further I suggest that you check out the [MVC.Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) project which has more features than the built in one.

Or because you are looking for customization targeting Bootstrap you can check out the **twitter.bootstrap.mvc** project ([intro blog post](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/20/twitter-bootstrap-mvc4-the-template-nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc4-projects/))

Some of its [features](https://github.com/erichexter/twitter.bootstrap.mvc):

- Runtime Scaffolding – default Index, Edit and Detail views.. You provide the POCOs and we will render the CRUD views.
- MVC code templates to generate new views from the mvc add view / add controller dialogs

The custom MVC Code Templates (still a work in progress) are available in a separate nuget packge:

```
PM> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.templates
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the T4 Templates, I will definitely take a look and possibly customize the scaffolding templates.

Comment: Boy, it would really be nice if someone from Microsoft would go ahead post a comprehensive set of Bootstrap T4 View templates for us.  They must exist as they are supporting Bootstrap in VS2013 http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/27/microsoft-adds-bootstrap-support-to-visual-studio-2013/.